# MusicDB in MySQL Multiple Foreign Keys to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am working on a music DB for a class project and I'm running into problems setting foreign keys for certain tables.

I have about 6 tables.

```
Songs
Artist
FeaturedArtist
Albums
Genres
SubGenres
RelatedGenres
RecordLabel
```

The issues are surrounding the following tables

```
create table Songs(Title varchar(75) not null, Artist varchar(40) not null, FeaturedArtist varchar(100), 
Album varchar(100), SongYear YEAR(4) not null, Genre char(10) not null, SubGenre varchar(30), Producer varchar(30) not null, 
SongWriter varchar(50), MusicVideo varchar(30000), Lyrics varchar(30000) not null,
             PRIMARY KEY (Title),
             FOREIGN KEY(Artist) REFERENCES Artist(Artist), 
             FOREIGN KEY(FeaturedArtist) REFERENCES FeaturedArtists(Artist), 
             FOREIGN KEY(Album) REFERENCES Albums(Album), 
             FOREIGN KEY(Genre) REFERENCES Genre(Genre), 
             FOREIGN KEY(SubGenre) REFERENCES SubGenre(SubGenre));

create table Artists(Artist varchar(40) not null, Genre varchar(10) not null, Band_Group varchar(40),  
             PRIMARY KEY(Artist),
             FOREIGN KEY Genre REFERENCES Genre(Genre));

create table Genre(Genre varchar(10) not null, RelatedGenres varchar(10) not null); PRIMARY KEY(Genre);
FOREIGN KEY RelatedGenres REFERENCES RalatedGenres(Genre);

create table RelatedGenres(Genre varchar(10) not null, RelatedGenre varchar(10));

create table SubGenre(SubGenre varchar(30) not null, Genre varchar(10) not null,
             PRIMARY KEY(SubGenre),
             FOREIGN KEY(Genre) REFERENCES Genre(Genre));
```

How can I arrange these tables in a way where I don't get errors for trying to use a foreign key such as Genre in more than one table.

Hope some of you can help!

Comment: Can you inlcude the exact error output?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I will get either #1005 - Can't create table `bpmtest`.`genre` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Comment: or a #1064 saying there is a syntax error where I reference the Foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem lies in your foreign key declarations. You need to specify the child table columns inside parentheses i.e. `FOREIGN KEY (Genre) REFERENCES Genre(Genre)` instead of `FOREIGN KEY Genre REFERENCES Genre(Genre)`

By tweaking the `Artists` and `Genre` tables it worked in my database.

```
create table RelatedGenres(Genre varchar(10) not null, RelatedGenre varchar(10));

create table Genre(Genre varchar(10) not null, RelatedGenres varchar(10) not null, PRIMARY KEY(Genre), FOREIGN KEY (RelatedGenres) REFERENCES RalatedGenres(Genre));

create table SubGenre(SubGenre varchar(30) not null, Genre varchar(10) not null,
         PRIMARY KEY(SubGenre),
         FOREIGN KEY(Genre) REFERENCES Genre(Genre));

create table Artists(Artist varchar(40) not null, Genre varchar(10) not null, Band_Group varchar(40),                PRIMARY KEY(Artist),              FOREIGN KEY (Genre) REFERENCES Genre(Genre));

create table Songs(Title varchar(75) not null, Artist varchar(40) not null, FeaturedArtist varchar(100), Album varchar(100), SongYear YEAR(4) not null, Genre char(10) not null, SubGenre varchar(30), Producer varchar(30) not null, SongWriter varchar(50), MusicVideo varchar(30000), Lyrics varchar(30000) not null,
         PRIMARY KEY (Title),
         FOREIGN KEY(Artist) REFERENCES Artists(Artist), 
         FOREIGN KEY(FeaturedArtist) REFERENCES FeaturedArtists(Artist), 
         FOREIGN KEY(Album) REFERENCES Albums(Album), 
         FOREIGN KEY(Genre) REFERENCES Genre(Genre), 
         FOREIGN KEY(SubGenre) REFERENCES SubGenre(SubGenre));
```

Comment: Thank You! However these all work up until I try to create the songs and albums table. I will look closely at what you wrote here as it is difficult to see the differences.

Comment: The only table that I'm getting errors from is the Songs table now.

Comment: This is the error message Create  table `bpmtest`.`songs` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `bpmtest`.`artist` not found in the data dictionary near 'FOREIGN KEY(Artist) REFERENCES Artist(Artist), 
         FOREIGN KEY(FeaturedArtist) REFERENCES FeaturedArtists(Artist), 
         FOREIGN KEY(Album) REFERENCES Albums(Album), 
         FOREIGN KEY(Genre) REFERENCES Genre(Genre), 
         FOREIGN KEY(SubGenre) REFERENCES SubGenre(SubGenre))'.

Comment: Your table is named `Artists`, not `Artist`. Looks like I may have missed that one myself. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I directed most of the atention to my featuredArtist table. But thank you! Seems we both overlooked the S.

Comment: Since MySQL is accepting the `CREATE TABLE` statements without complaining, it seems the foreign keys are not being enforced. This is probably due to the table engine being used. MyISAM (commonly the default table engine) does not support foreign keys, so it is blindly accepting the foreign key clauses in your statements. If you want to enforce referential integrity with foreign keys, I would recommend using InnoDB as your engine.